# Preciso que a repetição pare quando eu digitar "F"

Tags: c, algoritmo

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int O,i;
    float F,VI=0,VF=0;
    printf("Valor Inicial:"); scanf("%f",&VI);
    printf("Valor Final:"); scanf("%f",&VF);
    while (VI!=F)
    {
        if(VI<=VF)
            O=1;
        else 
            O=-1;

        for (i=VI;i!=VF+O;i=i+O)
        {
            printf("\n %d",i);
        }
        printf("\n#############################");
        printf("\nValor Inicial:"); scanf("%f",&VI);
        printf("\nValor Final:"); scanf("%f",&VF);

    }
}
```

Comment: corrija a indentação do seu programa...coloque 4 espaços no início de cada linha do programa

Comment: E qual o valor da variável F? Se suas variáveis são do tipo float o que você quer dizer com "quando eu digitar F"?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

A pergunta não deixa claro os critérios e eu até tinha fechado ela, mas como tem uma resposta que na verdade não diz onde é para colocar isto, de que jeito preferi responder, mas nas próximas perguntas dê mais detalhes do que deseja fazer, porque eu não garanto que esta seja a melhor solução. Pode ser que valores negativos não sejam aceitos, ou o 0.  assim a saída poderia ser feita por um critério diferente e nem precisar do pedido auxiliar para encerrar. Note que o código pode ser muito mais simples.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    while (1) {
        float vi, vf;
        printf("\n#############################");
        printf("\nValor Inicial: "); scanf("%f", &vi);
        printf("\nValor Final: "); scanf("%f", &vf);
        int o = (vi <= vf) ? 1 : -1;
        for (int i = vi; i != vf + o; i += o) printf("\n %d", i);
        char continuar;
        printf("\nDigite F para encerrar: "); scanf("%c", &continuar);
        if (continuar == 'F') break;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/7KyXen). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/WhileExit). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/ControlFlux/WhileExit.c).

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo mudar a estrutura de repetição para `while`.

```
while(condição){

}
```

Compare a variável em que você armazena o `input` do usuário com 'F':

```
while(var != 'F'){

}
```

O código só irá parar caso a variável for igual a F.

Basicamente a solução é essa.